# What are the trade offs between resource preload as a HTTP header or as a tag in the response?

Tags: html, http, web-performance

So a preload https://w3c.github.io/preload/ can be defined as a tag via declarative markup

```
<link rel="preload" href="/styles/other.css" as="style">
```

Or as a HTTP header

```
Link: <https://example.com/other/styles.css>; rel=preload; as=style
```

But what are the tradeoffs between the two? Under what circumstances should the tag be used and vica versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it should be kind of obvious. If it's in the HTML, you need to parse the HTML. That happens *after* parsing the headers, since you need the headers to know you're parsing HTML in the first place (and not, say, `image/jpeg` or `text/plain`).

Does this actually cause a performance difference in practice? That's quite impossible to tell in general, as with most performance questions. The main point is still separating I/O from execution, which is true for both approaches.

CDNs and proxies generally make use of headers for various access optimizations and caching. This is obviously cheaper than parsing the HTML, so maybe we'll see some recommendations to that effect :) For example, I can imagine a proxy that launches a preload based on the HTTP header before it even gets the HTTP header - just by observing common patterns in what kinds of requests usually mean what kinds of preloads. When the prediction fits, it can quite nicely eliminate latency in fetching this, especially on high-latency connections, and with long-running requests.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit (2024)**: Following @C.O.'s comment, I searched the web again and this is now recommended in web.dev: [How to implement rel=preload](https://web.dev/articles/preload-critical-assets#how_to_implement_relpreload):

> A benefit of specifying preload in the HTTP Header is that the browser
> doesn't need to parse the document to discover it, which can offer
> small improvements in some cases.

I've just implemented it, and I'm seeing something additional that I don't see mentioned anywhere: At least in Chrome, this header is also used when the page adding the HTTP header is itself preloaded. This means that the browser isn't required to fully load the page issuing the header to begin preloading its resources. If the page is preloaded, the process can initiate even prior to the user's navigation to it.

Original answer from 2022:

(Trying to add something valuable to @Luaan's answer)

I don't think it can cause a meaningful difference. Otherwise, for all CSS files, it would be a good thing to *always* have a header such as:

```
Link: </styles.css>; rel=preload; as=style
```

So the browser can start downloading CSS files (usually blocking) before parsing the HTML. But I have never seen this suggested anywhere. My personal tests on localhost seem to indicate that this saves only 1 millisecond in Chrome.

Comment: Try PageSpeed Insights particularly for mobile devices for some larger page with gzip compression etc. and this can indeed shave off a few hundred ms blocking time rather than being irrelevat and it is pretty simple to implement.

Comment: @C.O. I updated my answer, this may have been updated recently